# How can the knots TikZ library be used with current l3 (e.g. TeX Live 2015)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, expl3, latex3, tikz-knots

The `knots` library for TikZ seems to be incompatible with the current l3 packages as provided, for example, by TeX Live 2015.

The following example, taken from the library's documentation compiles fine with `pdflatex` from TeX Live 2014 but not from TeX Live 2015.

The error is as follows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...l:N \l__spath_tmpa_tl }\tl_case:Nnn 
                                                  \l__spath_tmpc_tl {\g__spa...
l.14   \end{knot}
```

What can I do to continue drawing knots with the current l3 packages?

*Please do not spend time on this question unless either (1) you find it an intrinsic source of edification and delight or (2) you work on the l3 stuff.*

I answered this question in trying to respond to another and thought the answer useful, even though I now think it unlikely to help the poster of the original question. Hence this one. I will post an answer here shortly.

I'm hoping that somebody who works on the `l3` stuff will have a better answer....

Comment: Fixed version available at https://github.com/loopspace/spath3

Comment: @LoopSpace Excellent! I guess it will be migrating to CTAN at some point? Thanks very much.

Comment: To be honest, it may be a little while before that happens.  The whole submit-to-CTAN process fills me with dread.  I _never_ get it right first time.  I'm sorely tempted to withdraw my packages from CTAN and make them available via github only.  I probably won't, but it's tempting ...

Comment: @LoopSpace I've had that experience, too. And the rules seem to (a) change and (b) not be stated anywhere! But it would be a shame to be stuck with a broken version of this in standard TeX distributions.

Comment: Finally found the time to do this and managed to get it uploaded without a hitch.  Should be available in a day or so.

Comment: Cool! Maybe somebody should ask a question 'What are the current rules...?' and whoever has got it wrong last could update the answer with the latest twists ... ;). I'm almost tempted to do this, actually, as a CW ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_if_exist:NF \tl_case:Nnn
 {
  \cs_new_eq:NN \tl_case:Nnn \tl_case:NnF
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

until the package gets updated.

All `_case` functions underwent a change in the naming scheme: `\<module>_case:Nnn` became

```
\<module>_case:NnF
```

with the addition of `\<module>_case:NnTF` and `\<module>_case:Nn` (when non true or false text is needed). The `T` argument is used in addition to the case code when a match is found.

Note: why the `\cs_if_exist:NF` wrapper? Because, if the code is run on an system still with an older `l3` kernel, it would cease to work if just `\cs_new_eq:NN` is used.

---

It can happen that the LaTeX team decides to deprecate a function or a set of them for several reasons. For instance, a function can become obsolete because of new functions with better features and consistent interface. In the case of the `\<module>_case:Nnn` functions, the new ones mainly have a better naming scheme that enhances consistency with booleans (also in them there are tests that evaluate to true or false).

When a function gets deprecated, the team doesn't remove it at once, but decides for a grace period, in order to give time to package developers for updating their software. New releases of the `l3` suite after the grace period has expired for a deprecated function will not have it any longer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29257/discussion-on-answer-by-egreg-how-can-the-knots-tikz-library-be-used-with-curren).